# Get user info from another table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have `Order` table where user orders will be stored with their `id` and also have status of `0 / 1` to show if that order is paid by user or no.

Now I want to show in their profile that for example they have 10 orders and 3 paid.

I can get that number of total orders which is 10 but i have problem with getting the number of those 3 orders that has been paid.

Currently I have this:

```
$ordersd = DB::table('orders')->where('status', Auth::user()->username)->pluck('status')->count();
```

But it is not what I need cause I need to specified that `count` for me only orders with status `1` which belongs to logged user.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you comparing `status` with `Auth::user()->username` inside where condition ?

Does it makes any sense ?

```
$ordersd = DB::table('orders')->where('status', Auth::user()->username)
               ->pluck('status')->count();
```

So, change it to

```
$ordersd = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->count();
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: I understand that bro but it doesn't work why? cause it will return status 1 for all users! i want to get only those columns belongs to logged user.

Comment: I need to say return this status for logged user only and not all users.

Comment: @RobertNicjoo How are you tracking which orders belong to which users? Is there a user id or name field in the Orders table?

Comment: @RobertNicjoo I've updated my answer try latest one please.

Comment: Do you really need the `pluck()` call? Since you only need the count you don't need to retrieve all the rows that match the query when the database can count them for you and just send you the number.

Comment: @ChrisBaldwin pluck is unnecessary here as you say. I'll update answer

Comment: @RobertNicjoo Congrats you 've got solution

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this to get the count of the paid orders:

```
$ordersd = DB::table('orders')
             ->where([ [ 'status', '=', 1 ], 
                       [ 'user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id]
                    ])
             ->count();
```

To get the total number of orders:

```
$ordersd = DB::table('orders')
             ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
             ->count();
```